# How can we use $(im(A))^\perp = \ker(A^T)$ to prove $rank(A)=rank(A^T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is it that these two statements are essentially equivalent? $(im(A))^\perp$ represents all vectors orthogonal to the $im(A)$. Yet I'm not sure what this being equal to $\ker(A^T)$ exactly means, nor how it relates to the rank of $A$ and $A^T$. I feel like some of my confusion may be stemming from my shoddy understanding of $A^T$.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, what is $\mathop{im}(A)$?

Comment: @BennettGardiner The image of $A$, or the column space of $A$.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things we need to prove the equivalence here:

- the rank of a matrix is the dimension of its image 
  $\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank} \DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}
  \DeclareMathOperator{\null}{null}$
- The rank nullity theorem: $\rank(A) + \null(A) = \rank(A^T) + \null(A^T) = n$, where $\null(A)$ means $\dim \ker(A)$
- for any subspace $U$, $\dim(U) + \dim(U^\perp) = n$

From there, we have
$$
\rank(A^T) = \dim(\im(A^T)) = \dim(\ker(A)^\perp) =\\
n - \dim(\ker(A)) = n - \null(A) =\\
n- (n - \rank(A)) = \\
\rank(A)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in finite dimensional space $E$ we have

$$(im(A))^\perp\oplus im(A)=E$$
so with the rank-nullity theorem the result is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{rank }A 
= n - \dim \ker A
$$

Now using 
$$
\ker A = \text{im }A^\perp\\
\dim S^\perp = n-\dim S
$$
you can conclude.