# Why is the dimension of the left nullspace m-r?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have recently learned that instead of transposing the $mxn$ matrix A and finding a basis for $N(A^T)$ through direct computation, I could find the elementary row operation matrix $E$ that satisfies $EA=R$, where $R=rref(A)$. The rows of $E$ corresponding to the last $m-r$ zero rows of $R$ would then give me a basis for $N(A^T)$, where $r=rank(A)$. The detailed method is described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3878698).

I can see that these rows of $E$ are solutions to $A^Tx=0$, but I can't seem to wrap my head around why these $m-r$ rows span the left nullspace of A, and why they are guaranteed to be linearly independent. As a consequence, I also don't understand why $dim(N(A^T))=m-r$. So far all the books and resources I have consulted skimp on the explanation or proof. Could someone explain or provide a proof that the last $m-r$ rows of $E$ forms a basis for $N(A^T)$. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the Rank-Nullity theorem? I haven't read your post fully, but that seems relevant

Comment: Yes. But is it always the case that $rank(A^T)=rank(A)$?

Comment: It is always the case. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1014915/815585)